# nodejs API restrictions ... Not allowed from postman .. same origin access allowed

Tags: node.js, api, security

I have created few API on nodejs a d want to consume in same nodejs app.  Even I have ensure  cross origin to my domain.
It's only preventing cross domain and not allowed API.

But when using postman it's allowed .

Please help to provide how to restrict my nodejs api to be used by  my app internal in angular and should not allow cross domain and postman.

Answer (score 1):

Cross domain protections are implemented only in a browser to protect end-user browser security.  They do not apply to http requests made from Postman or from node.js or from any other programmatic tool, only from the browser.

There is no way to keep your API from being called by other agents besides your own web app.  This is just the way of the web.  For your web page to be able to use the API in the browser, that API has to be open to the public.

The usual way to provide some protections on such APIs is to require some sort of user login in order to use the API.  Your own web app can have a logged in user and your server can require a certain login cookie be on the http request before your server will fulfill the request.  This too can be used by 3rd party tools such as Postman, but they would have to first obtain an appropriate login cookie.

To prevent abuse even in these cases where they get a login cookie, you would need to track usage on your server and if you detect any irregular patterns or abusive patterns (often with some sort of rate limiting detection logic), then you can temporarily or permanently ban that user login.